# Google sheets: Insert a cell variable to determine tab name

Tags: google-sheets, variables, filter, tabs, interrupt

I'm looking to have my Google sheet pull in a random tab to populate its fields. I have a =RANDBETWEEN giving me a number, and I'm looking to have something like:

=FILTER('Story 1'!2:2,'Story 1'!2:2<>"") but where I can change out the "1" in "Story 1" for the digit generated by the RANDBETWEEN. How can I interrupt this properly?

I've tried a couple of INDIRECT calls but I can't get it to parse right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `INDIRECT()` in this way-

```
=FILTER(INDIRECT("'Story " & RANDBETWEEN(1,5) & "'!2:2"),INDIRECT("'Story " & RANDBETWEEN(1,5) & "'!2:2")<>"")
```

Comment: Thanks! I modified this a little to do the trick. I kept the RANDBETWEEN in a separate cell to reference because sometimes the two in this formula generated different values, but that works perfect now!